# Quantized level method

Tags: java, android, math

Trying to find a more elegant way to create an int that has discrete levels.  My example only shows 6 different levels but I am wanting to do this for 45 different levels, so  don't want 45 if elses.  Not sure what this is called in math and so can't seem to find what I am looking for.

```
sd = some double value

int level = 0;

if (Double.compare(sd, 0.41) >= 0) {
    level = 5;
} else if(Double.compare(sd, 0.25) >= 0) {
    level = 4;
} else if(Double.compare(sd, 0.11) >= 0) {
    level = 3;
} else if(Double.compare(sd, 0.05) >= 0) {
    level = 2;
} else if(Double.compare(sd, 0.02) >= 0) {
    level = 1;
}
```

................

Latest Update FYI these were the values I needed to quantize:
As you can see I needed something a little more elegant,  Used Navigable Map answer

```
public static final int[] Levels = { 
        3100, 3250, 3383, 3517, 3650, 
        3673, 3695, 3718, 3740, 3760, 
        3780, 3800, 3820, 3853, 3885,
        3918, 3950, 3975, 4000, 4025, 4050
        };
```

Comment: Is each condition always 1/2 the previous one?

Comment: no this was just an example so I edited it so others won't see that either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html

```
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
map.put(0, 0);    // 0..4     => 0
map.put(5, 1);    // 5..10    => 1
map.put(10, 2);   // 10..100  => 2
......
```

You can implement it with Double data type too.

Comment: you were faster to write this... to retrieve the level use simply `floorEntry(sd).getValue()`

Comment: Where is NavigableMap?  Its not in java.util.

Comment: @JPM: You must be using a pretty old version of Java.  It's been in since 1.6 which came out five years ago.

Comment: Actually using android 2.2 and its not in there.

Comment: Turns out the NavigableMap was introduced 2.3 (9) but since I am building for 2.2 its not available. But I like the solution, I may try and manually add the classes to use your/Kru's code.

Answer (score 3):

I would store your thresholds in a collection and then find the location of the highest threshold in relation to your input.

Example

```
double[] thresholds = { 0.0, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2 };

int level(double d) {
    for(int i = 0; i < thresholds.length; i++) {
        if(thresholds[i] > d) return i;
    }
    return thresholds.length + 1;
}
```

Now this is currently order n. You can speed this up by using a binary search to make it order log n.

Comment: Since binary search is built into Java, it would not only make your code faster but also pretty short:  `int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(thresholds, d); return pos < 0 ? -(pos + 1) : pos;` (Disclaimer: I haven't thought through whether this would ceil or floor the level).

Comment: @Mark that's exactly the reason why I didn't put it in there hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array `double[] boundary = { 0.4, 0.2, 0.1...};` with all your level boundaries.  Then loop through this array until your value is greater than the boundary.  The index of your loop is your discrete level.

(Note, if your levels are actually logarithmic, as others have noted you don't necessarily need the custom array...)

Comment: Hmm better...still seems a little brute force.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a base-2 logarithmically based function to me.

EDIT: OK, so your real function is not exactly logarithmically based.  There's a few things you could try.  I guess the first thing I'd try is some kind of regression (logarithmic ?)to try and get the values. If that doesn't work, there's always the table method suggested by others.  Another numerical solver method that I've wanted to try (but haven't yet) is [Eureqa](http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa).

Comment: Just an example but it won't be logical when I make it for 45 different levels.